# Simulate STM32F4 brownout reset using STM32F100

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, stm32, stm32f4

The STM32F4 MCU has a brownout reset feature. According to [the manual](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/DM00031020.pdf), section 5.2.2, when the supply voltage VDD drops below the selected VBOR threshould, a device reset is generated. After reset, I can check the BORRSTF flag in register RCC_CSR (see section 6.3.21 of the manual) to see whether the reset was due to a brownout.

I'd like to simulate this behavior in the STM32F100, which lacks a brownout reset feature. My idea is to use the programmable voltage detector (section 4.2.2 in [the manual](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/CD00246267.pdf)) to generate an interrupt in EXTI line 16. When the interrupt handler is called, I'll generate a software reset; I can verify, after reset, that the reason was a software reset by way of the SFTRSTF flag in register RCC_CSR (see section 6.3.10 of the manual). Since I don't generate a software reset anywhere else in my code, I can be certain it was due to a brownout.

Here's what I'm looking to know:

- Can anyone see a flaw in this idea?
- Would an actual brownout wipe the SFTRSTF flag in question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see no major flaw in this design, but consider few limitations:

- as this is software based brownout reset (not configured in option bytes), it will not work until your code configures it (so voltage drop just after power up will be undetected),
- as it uses interrupt it will not work if interrupt with higher or equal interrupt priority is already executing.

As far is I know reset flags must be cleared manually (at least in F4), so:

- brownout will not wipe software reset flag,
- you must clear this flag on startup, otherwise after other reset you can have multiple flags.